# Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I’m executing the code in their own contexts, but it’s causing data to be out of sync in the main threads context.  So I need to refresh the entity after the other contexts finish their work before I can update it.

Unfortunately, I’m getting a OptimisticConcurrencyException and can’t figure out which entity it is that is the issue and needs to be refreshed? Is there a way to find out which entity it is that is causing the OptimisticConcurrencyException?  This message is not helpful at all…

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store
>   update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of
>   rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities
>   were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries. --->
>   System.Data.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or
>   delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities
>   may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: Perhaps, `DbUpdateConcurrencyException.Entries` property can help to detect unsaved entities.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best solution would be to just create a new `context` in the main thread context after the other threads have finished.

Otherwise, if you need to reuse the `context`, here's a handy method for refreshing your context objects.

```
    public void RefreshAll()
    {
        // Get all objects in state manager with entityKey
        // (context.Refresh will throw an exception otherwise)
        var refreshableObjects = (from entry in
                ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(
                                                    EntityState.Deleted
                                                  | EntityState.Modified
                                                  | EntityState.Unchanged)
                                  where entry.EntityKey != null
                                  select entry.Entity);

        ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
    }
```